# Write on Player Prefs from Unity and read Shared Preferences from Android returns wrong value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, unity-game-engine, android-sharedpreferences

I'm working on a [unity](/questions/tagged/unity) game exported to [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android). I have an *Activity* to save values on **SharedPreferences** that will be retrieve from *Unity Activity* and updated from **PlayerPrefs**. Also these values will be read from **SharedPreferences** from the Main Activity.

The values that I get not match with the values that I write on the main activity and only reads when I close the entire application.

> Here is my code and how actually works.

The Main Activity save a value on *Shared Preferences* and launch the **UnityPlayerActivity**.

[image]

```
public void writeOnSharedAndLaunch(String text) {
    String sharedPreferenceName = context.getPackageName() + ".v2.playerprefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferenceName, MODE_PRIVATE);;
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("PlayerName", playerText.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

From *Unity* I get the value from **PlayerPrefs** without problems, but when I update the preference on *PlayerPrefs* and return to *Main Activity* the value is the same.

[image]
[image]

> I completely close the application and I open it again.

And as you can see the value changes but the spaces are replaced with **%20** value.

[image]

This is my code from *Unity Controller*:

```
public void saveOnDataFromShared(string name) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", name);
    textShared.text = name;
}
public void loadStringFromPlayerPrefs() {
    textShared.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PlayerName", "Default value");
}
```

I can't figure it out what happen on the process, any help is appreciated.

Comment: were you able to figure out? and bro I too successfully integrated my unity to android but can you help me how to pass data(a string ) to unity? This is my question  please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370546/retrieve-data-from-android-activity-to-unity3d

Comment: I didn't be able to figure it out, we decided to handle all the config and process in one platform. The exporting/integration process was too time consuming and thats why we decide to choose only one platform. According to your question _PlayerPrefs_ is the best way to save info in game sessions

Comment: Do you know how to pass a string to unity that is retrieved from firebase ?Although I can successfully pass normal strings now

Answer (score 0):

What you may be missing is saving the changes done to Prefs by calling:

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

So, your code should look like:

```
public void saveOnDataFromShared(string name) {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", name);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    textShared.text = name;
}
```